# unable to bind JSON data to list in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, data-binding, windows-phone-8

Im new to phone development, When I bind JSON data to list box in c#, I get a blank screen, my list is not getting populated,I get my JSON response from web service successfully,My code is as follows

```
 public void callbackwall(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string json = e.Result.ToString();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
        {
            var example = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<listreadqueries>>(json);
            ServerList.ItemsSource = example;

         }
        }


    public class readqueriesObject
    {
        public string customer_read_status { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string Inserted_Date { get; set; }
        public string Query_From_Id { get; set; }
        public string Query_From_Name { get; set; }
        public string Query_Id { get; set; }
        public string Query_Status { get; set; }
        public string Query_To_Id { get; set; }
        public string Query_To_Name { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public int count { get; set; }
        public List<object> historyList { get; set; }
        public string Query_Type { get; set; }
    }
    public class listreadqueries
    {
        public List<readqueriesObject> queries { get; set; }
    }
}
```

}

The JSON response im getting is `[{"customer_read_status":"read","description":"Maecenas nec elit metus. Donec porttitor porttitor felis vitae hendrerit. Sed a interdum magna amet.\r\n","Inserted_Date":"Aug 14, 2013 at 01:22"},{....},{..}]`

My XAML code is as follows

```
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,20" Width="300">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=description}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your deserialization should be

```
var example = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<readqueriesObject>>(json);
```

No need for `listreadqueries`

PS: your json is an *array*, not an object cotaining array (`{queries:[...]}`)